# get textfield cell td in extjs grid 4.0

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am using extjs 4.0 version. when I update extjs grid textfield value, I need to apply css to td. so on change i need to get td of that cell in change listener.

```
'change': function(textField, newValue, oldValue, eOpts){
}
```

I tired 'this.getEl()' but no luck. any other pointers?

Comment: Do you want to change the color after the textfield goes or before it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use a renderer event on your header:

```
{header: ... renderer: fctChangeColor},

function fctChangeColor(currentCellValue, metadata, record, rowIndex, colIndex, myStore )
{
      if(fctValidate(currentCellValue) == false)
        metadata.css = "myNewClass";

      return currentCellValue;

}
```